# Can I have multiple Azure DevOps organisations with MSDN Subscription?

Tags: azure-devops

I've tried to find an answer to this but nothing that gives anything definite.

I have a MSDN subscription (Visual Studio Enterprise). I have used the benefit from that to create a Azure DevOps environment that works well.

I am looking to create a new set of projects for a specific company, and it seems logical to create a new 'Organisation' to hold that code and work items.

Can you do this with the MSDN license? Or do I need to buy a subscription to bill that Azure DevOps instance to?

Comment: you can certainly create multiple Organizations and use the same MSDN license to manage them.  When you want to use non-free features, you have to attach billing and not sure if your MSDN benefit subscription can support more than one org. I am supporting multiple orgs using Enterprise Dev/Test but it's part of EA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I have multiple Azure DevOps organisations with MSDN Subscription?

The short answer is NO.

Visual Studio Enterprise and Azure devops are two different products that have their own licenses, they could not share a licenses.

Besides, you can have multiple Azure DevOps organisations for free, but the free tier of resources in your organization is restricted, the Free tier includes:

> - Five Azure DevOps users (Basic).
> - Five Azure Artifacts users.
> - Free Tier of Microsoft-hosted CI/CD (one concurrent job, up to 30    hours per month).
> - One self-hosted CI/CD concurrent job.
> - 20,000 virtual user minutes of cloud-based load testing.

When you need more than the free tier of resources in your organization, or to buy other features for your users that are offered by Microsoft or other companies via the Visual Studio Marketplace, on the Azure DevOps tab, you need buy a subscription to bill that Azure DevOps instance.

Check following threads for some more details:

[Billing overview for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/overview?view=azure-devops)

[Pricing for Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/)

[Compare features between plans](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/compare-features/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: To clarify is that you can only have one attached Org to the MSDN subscription, but for Enterprise Pay-As-You-Go, you can attach multiple Orgs as long as they are part of the same tenant.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Leo entirely answers the question.
Since you do have Azure DevOps as a MSDN benefit beyond the free tier.

[MSDN Azure DevOps Benefits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/vs-azure-devops)

So the question as I understand it is, does the MSDN Azure DevOps benefits follow the user? Or is it tied to just one Organization? Luckily this has just changed or at least been clarified, not sure how it worked before.

Still only states the regular payd plans, and not the MSDN benefits, but I can't see any reason why this should be any different.

### One license works across multiple organizations

> Starting in late June,
>   users will only need one license per Azure subscription, even if they
>   are part of multiple Azure DevOps organizations. This means that
>   regardless of how many organizations a user is a part of in a given
>   Azure subscription, they will only need and only pay for one Basic or
>   one Basic + Test Plans license.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/a-simpler-way-to-buy-azure-devops/

Comment: One MSDN or VS Ent license or Test Prof license etc can be tied to only one Azure Subscription. You can not use one MSDN license or VS ENt or Developer or Test Prof across multiple Azure tenant for free. Its only attached to one subscription. Either your personal subscription (pay-as-you-go) or Enterprise Agreement/Organization Azure Subscription. Now one can have many org within a subscription and so one MSDN License or VS ENt or Dev or Test prof can be used as one license across multiple org within that subscription.